# When to set redirectPath property in Laravel 5 auth trait

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait used by Laravel's default `AuthController` class the following code is used:

```
return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
```

The `redirectPath()` function is as follows:

```
public function redirectPath()
{
    if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath'))
    {
        return $this->redirectPath;
    }
    return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
}
```

Reading this code there are two different properties I could set on the `AuthController` class: `redirectPath` and `redirectTo`. `redirectPath` takes precedence over `redirectTo`.

When I want to change the default page to redirect to from `/home` to `/` I assume it would be best to set the `redirectTo` property. What is the intended use of the `redirectPath` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe since the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` is a trait and can be used by different classes both two property checks are for backwards compability with different classes, but the logic has same purpose.

Generally I suggest you to use `redirectPath` property, because it is the first condition in that function and if for any reason you do not pay attention and use the `redirectTo` property in controller that extends another controller that has defined `redirectPath` you will end up thinking what is wrong and why your controller redirects you to different path.

Comment: It doesn't look like the `AuthController` class ever set the `redirectPath` property by default (they did at one time set the `redirectTo` property). Everything else seems right though so I have marked it as the accepted answer. See my answer for some more details I dug up.

Comment: Ah sorry maybe you are right. I looked `AuthController` on one of my projects, but seems like the property is not there by default, I have added it manually. Sorry for the confusion I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I dug up some history on these properties and the `redirectPath()` function.

## 30 Nov 2014

Redirects were orginally hardcoded in the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/cc1c35069a7bbc3717487d931fbd80b8e6641a90

```php
+    return redirect('/home');
```

Redirects were changed to `redirect($this->redirectTo)`
https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/a71926653a573f32ca7a31527c7644c4305c1964#diff-b72935cc9bfd1d3e8139fd163ae00bf5

```php
-    return redirect('/home');
+    return redirect($this->redirectTo);
```

## 1 Dec 2014

`redirectPath()` function was added
https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/dd78c4fe763859d11e726477125b7d1a00c860c0#diff-b72935cc9bfd1d3e8139fd163ae00bf5

```php
+    public function redirectPath()
+    {
+        return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
+    }
```

And redirects changed to `redirect($this->redirectPath())`

```php
-    return redirect($this->redirectTo);
+    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
```

At the same time, the properties in `AuthController` were removed
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/57a6e1ce7260444719dd3de1fdd7c58cdcdba362

```php
-    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

## 7 Feb 2015

`redirectPath` property was added to the `redirectPath()` function:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/63a534a31129be4cec4f5a694342d7020e2d7f07#diff-b72935cc9bfd1d3e8139fd163ae00bf5

```php
     public function redirectPath()
     {
+        if (property_exists($this, 'redirectPath'))
+        {
+            return $this->redirectPath;
+        }
     return property_exists($this, 'redirectTo') ? $this->redirectTo : '/home';
     }
```

## Conclusion

It looks like the correct property to be using is `redirectPath` as it is consistent with the `redirectPath()` function. It is also designed to override any older `redirectTo` properties that may have been added.

Comment: nice ...*applause*